# Play ogg inside a page?

Tags: firefox, browser, video, html, ogg

I was pretty surprised when i saw http://www.vorbis.com/music/Hydrate-Kenny_Beltrey.ogg link not give me a download option but had a player that was not flash playing the audio back. (FireFox)

Is there a way i can embed this onto a page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [HTML5 `Audio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox) tag.

P.S. Although you tagged as `firefox`, Chrome, Safari and Opera 10.5 also have support for `audio`

Comment: Note that out of all of them, Safari does not support Vorbis audio (because QuickTime doesn't, unless the user has installed XiphQT). An alternate `source` tag could provide a fallback, such as wav or mp3

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5 to embed this on a page, but it will not play back consistently across browsers.

The only way to get consistent audio/video playback across browsers is to use a plugin and Flash has the widest user penetration.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the HTML5 [`<audio>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox).
Note that it's not supported by IE.

Comment: Google finds at least a couple of free java applets capable of playing ogg/vorbis, that's a possible IE-compatible fallback solution.